# How to convert Php regular expression into js

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a regular expression in PHP and its working fine but i want to use it in js as well can any please tell me how to do that i am not much familiar with it

In php this expression is working like this it allow hyphen symbol (-) between number and character but remove hyphen symbol between characters and replace it with white space Like if i use any of this string

```
$string ="Al-Abbas - Manama - 100" or
$string ="100 - Al-Abbas - Manama"

$repl = preg_replace('/\d\h*-\h*(*SKIP)(*F)|-(?!\h*\d)/', ' ', $string);
```

after this i am getting this output

```
Al Abbas Manama - 100
100 - Al Abbas Manama
```

i want to do same like this in javascript how can i convert this expression in javascript or any other way to do like this in javascript.

Comment: you can't, you need to design your pattern (or your code) for javascript. Use capture groups, and a function as replacement.

Comment: Can you please guide me how i can make for javascript i haven't done before so i have no idea about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this pattern that captures what you want to avoid. Since `\h` doesn't exists in javascript you can emulate it using `[^\S\r\n]`. The replacement function returns the group when it exists or a space:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/(\d[^\S\r\n]*-)|-(?![^\S\r\n]*\d)/g, function (_, g) {
    return g ? g : ' '; });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str="100 - Al-Abbas - Manama";
var newstr = str.replace(/\d\h*-\h*(*SKIP)(*F)|-(?!\h*\d)/, ' ');
```

Comment: not working showing error i think you miss inverted commas ..?

Comment: the character class `\h` doesn't exist in javascript nor the backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)`